# How can I replace the TemplateService with the RazorEngineService?

Tags: c#, razor, html-email

I have the code as shown below, and I want to replace the TemplateService with the newer RazorEngineService. Could you show me how to replace it in my code?

PS: I've checked https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ but I get some exceptions when I try to refactor the code to RazorEngineService.

```
public class ReminderEmail
{
    string templateFolderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmailTemplates");
    string templateFilePath;
    ReminderEmailModel model;

    public ReminderEmail(ReminderEmailModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;
        try
        {
            templateFilePath = Path.Combine(templateFolderPath, "ReminderEmail.cshtml");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            //TODO: log file not found here
        }
    }


    public string GetHtmlBody()
    {
        var templateService = new TemplateService();
        var emailHtmlBody = templateService.Parse(File.ReadAllText(templateFilePath), model, null, null);
        return emailHtmlBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606132/templating-using-new-razorengine-api?answertab=votes#tab-top