# Razor Templating and Parsing could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to use Razor pages to template for HTML emails and I keep hitting a problem When running a function like `Engine.Razor.RunCompile()` OR 'TemplateService.Parse()' I get a runtime error in my asp.net core MVC webpage

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.CodeDom, >Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find >the file specified.'

Even extremely simple examples give me the error:

```
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating; // For extension methods.

string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
var result =
    Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new { Name = "World" });
```

This is from http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ I did install the RazorEngine Package

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606132/templating-using-new-razorengine-api#:%7E:text=Painless%20template%20compilation%20%3A%20Engine.Razor.Compile%20%28templatePath%2C%20%22templateNameInTheCache%22%2C%20modelType%29%3B,string%20myParsedTemplate%20%3D%20Engine.Razor.RunCompile%20%28templatePath%2C%20%22templateNameInTheCache%22%2C%20null%2C%20model%29) but none of the examples would work for me.

I've just been testing in the home controller. Here is my code. You can see by the comments lots of trial and only errors.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OperationalForecast.Models;
using OperationalForecast.Models.EmailTemplateModels;
using OperationalForecast.Services;
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Configuration;
using RazorEngine.Templating;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace OperationalForecast.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private IDistrictServices districtlist { get; set; }
        private IEmailServices emailservices { get; set; }

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IDistrictServices dataservice, IEmailServices emailservices)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            districtlist = dataservice;
            this.emailservices = emailservices;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(districtlist.GetAllDistricts());
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

    
        public string SendTestEmail2() //this is the method I'm testing templating
        {

            string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
            var result =
                Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new { Name = "World" });

            var approvaltemplate = new ApprovalEmailTemplate {district_name ="Akron", hire_date=new DateTime(2024,1,1), class_size=10, forecasted_need=5 };
            string forparsing = @"class size is @Model.class_size";
            var templateService = new TemplateService();
            //var templatefile = @"EmailTemplates\CreatedNewHireClassApproval.cshtml";
            //string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(templatefile);
            //var emailhtmlbody = templateService.Parse(forparsing, approvaltemplate, null, null);
            var emailhtmlbody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(forparsing, "CreatedNewHireClassApproval", null, approvaltemplate);

            //var key = new RazorEngine.Templating.NameOnlyTemplateKey("EmailTemplate", RazorEngine.Templating.ResolveType.Global, null);
            //RazorEngine.Engine.Razor.AddTemplate(key, new RazorEngine.Templating.LoadedTemplateSource("Ala ma kota"));
            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            //RazorEngine.Engine.Razor.RunCompile(key, sw);
            //string emailhtmlbody = sb.ToString();

            //var templateManager = new ResolvePathTemplateManager(new[] { rootPath });

            //var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
            //{
            //    TemplateManager = templateManager
            //};

            //Engine.Razor = RazorEngineService.Create(config);

            //string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\tristenhannah\\OneDrive - USIC LLC\\Documents\\OperationalForecastApplication\\OperationalForecast\\OperationalForecast\\EmailTemplates\\CreatedNewHireClassApproval.cshtml");

            //var emailhtmlbody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile("C:\\Users\\tristenhannah\\OneDrive - USIC LLC\\Documents\\OperationalForecastApplication\\OperationalForecast\\OperationalForecast\\EmailTemplates\\CreatedNewHireClassApproval.cshtml", "templateKey", null, approvaltemplate);



            EmailModel newEmail = new EmailModel { ToEmail = "tristenhannah@usicllc.com", Subject = "test", Body = emailhtmlbody, IsHtml = true };

            
            return emailservices.SendEmail(newEmail).ToString();



        }
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make it work.
https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2021/03/18/server-side-templating-in-net-core-with-razor/

I had to uninstall RazorEngine and install RazorEngine.NetCore

Then this code worked:

```
var approvaltemplate = new ApprovalEmailTemplate { district_name = "Akron", hire_date = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1), class_size = 10, forecasted_need = 5 };
var templatefile = @"EmailTemplates\CreatedNewHireClassApproval.cshtml";
string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(templatefile);

var emailhtmlbody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(contents, "template", null, approvaltemplate);
```